# Problem with MIB_IFTABLE and MIB_IFROW for byte transmission

Tags: c++, windows, networking, vpn

Im using `MIB_IFTABLE` and `MIB_IFROW` to get the number of bytes transmitted and received. Everything looks fine, and values are correct in case of using WIFI alone. But when I use VPN connection over WIFI these values are not correct for WIFI adapter. Interestingly I'm getting correct values for VPN adapter. And if I see status of any of these adapters (right click and see status), all these values given by windows are correct. Here are my questions:

1. Is there any other way of getting number of bytes transferred over adapter?
2. Is there a way to tell whether adapter is VPN or not? (as all VPN adapters are shows as Local Area Connection)
3. If you are connected to VPN, is there a possibility of bytes getting transferred through other than this VPN adapter? (forget about split tunneling, consider very simple case)

I use vs2005, win7.